# SSD1306 unable to display Text and waveform cohesively.Why?

Tags: ssd1306

Here is my code I am collecting data using an ECG sensor and trying to enhance the incoming data by stretching it across the x axis. Which results in this.
[image]

After this the screen eventually just goes black. What am I doing wrong?
This is my code.

```
#include <U8glib.h> 
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(12, 11, 8, 9, 10);
int Buffer[128];int Buffer2[128];int max=0;
//int largest;
void pageECG();     // Page-1


const int pageCount = 2;
int p;
void (*pages[pageCount])() = {pageECG};
int duration [pageCount] = {10000};
void setup() {
  
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_unifont);
  u8g.setColorIndex(1);
  p = 0;
  Serial.begin(9600); 

}

void loop()
{
u8g.firstPage();
  do {  
    (*pages[p])();
  } while( u8g.nextPage() );
  delay(duration[p]);
  p = p+1;
  if (p == pageCount)
    p=0;
}
void pageECG() {  
for(int x = 0;x < 128;x++) 
{
Buffer[x] =(analogRead(A0)*0.075);//This loop takes data input
delay(5);
if(Buffer[x]<32&&Buffer[x]!=2)
x-=2;
if(Buffer[x]>32&&Buffer[x]!=62)
x+=2;
Serial.println(Buffer[x]);
}  

for(int x = 0;x < 127;x++) 
{
u8g.setFont(u8g_font_unifont);
u8g.drawStr( 0, 60, "ECG");
u8g.drawLine(x, Buffer[x], x,Buffer[x+1]); //OP to OLED for BP

}}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what you are doing in the for loop where the data is read in? You manipulate the index variable `x` in a way that it is possible you get negative indexes. Also only three cases store a value subsequentially, i.e when the read value is 2, 32 or 62. In all other cases the index is recomputed. It's complete unpredictable, what this algorithm does. And the output you showed us is possible. `The drawLine` is also suspectable to me, shouldn't it be `u8g.drawLine(x, Buffer[x], x+1,Buffer[x+1]);`. I changed the 2nd `x` to `x+1`. And, I don't see code to clear the page before redraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one problem is this: You have made an array of pointer to function, but only initialized the first of the two, to `pageECG`.

```cpp
const int pageCount = 2;
int p;
void (*pages[pageCount])() = {pageECG};
```

The last line there roughly equivalent to:

```cpp
void (*pages[pageCount])() = {pageECG, nullptr};
```

Later in `loop()` you have:

```cpp
  u8g.firstPage();
  do {  
    (*pages[p])();
  } while( u8g.nextPage() );
  delay(duration[p]);
  p = p+1;
  if (p == pageCount)
    p=0;
```

After the first execution of `loop()`, `p` is 1.  Since it was not 2, it was not reset by your `if (p == pageCount) p=0;`  So on the next pass through `loop()`, `(*pages[p])();` is     `(*pages[1])();`  where `pages[1]` is `nullptr`.

In practice, what you're doing is generating and executing an AVR `icall` (indirect call) instruction to address 0x0000 (`nullptr` representation) to the reset vector.  So, your sketch starts over almost like a reset, except the hardware has not been reset.  Importantly, the interrupts are still configured as they were and the global interrupt flag is on, which means all manner of potential weirdness if one of them manages to execute before you get back ground `setup().`  So, it's difficult to say exactly why you're seeing what you're seeing.  But, it doesn't surprise me as a potential outcome.  And it may not be the *only* problem; just *a* problem.